# Is Harvest Moon a New Begining related to Harvest Moon DS?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

After getting Allan, I keep seeing Nami from Harvest Moon DS in him and have been wondering if he is a relative or possibly Nami's son.

Is Harvest Moon a New Beginning related to Harvest Moon DS in terms of timeline?